# conn.on('speaking') does not trigger for discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, chatbot

I'm working on a little discord bot. One of the things I'm trying to get it to do is join a voiceChannel and listen to the person speaking there, writing the audio to a file. I think what I'm trying is the way forward but I must be doing something wrong.
What I have for audio part:

```
    else if(listening === true){
        const voiceChannel = client.channels.get("644587330673311788");
        log.info('listening = true');
        voiceChannel.join()
        .then(conn => {
            log.info('ready!');
            // create our voice receiver
            const receiver = conn.createReceiver();

            conn.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {
                log.info("speaking conn up...");
                    if (speaking) {
                        log.info(`I'm listening to ${user}`);
                        //This is where the audiostream will be created/written to file
                    }
                });
            })
        .catch(console.log);
    }
```

This happens inside the `client.on('message', message => {` and I can see the bot join the right voiceChannel, then it logs 'listening = true' and finally it logs 'ready!' after which nothing happens anymore.

So something must be wrong with the `conn.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {` part. One of the things I've tried is switching `speaking` out for `guildMemberSpeaking` though that made no difference. I've had very little luck trting to find a solution as every source I find uses this `conn.on('speaking'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try listening to the connection's `debug`, `warn` and `error` events and log the output for each. Might help you narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open issue about it on github: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3524

It was fixed on the v12 (not out yet, only on github) and on the 11-5dev (the v11 updated with every patch).

If you want to use it, from github:

```
npm install git+https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js#11.5-dev
```